# How to have Macro get rid of gridlines

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub AddRowAndSheet()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim newSheetName As String
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Static sheetCounter As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim initialRowHeight As Double
    
    Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List of Assets")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet 'List of Assets' not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("MyTable")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Table 'MyTable' not found in 'List of Assets'!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    
    If newRow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to add a new row to the table!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    LastRow = tbl.ListRows.Count
    newRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Asset " & LastRow
    
    initialRowHeight = tbl.ListRows(1).Range.RowHeight
    
    newRow.Range.RowHeight = initialRowHeight
    
    sheetCounter = sheetCounter + 1
    newSheetName = "Sheet" & sheetCounter
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List of Assets"))
    newSheet.Name = newSheetName
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If newSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to create a new sheet!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=newSheet
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Failed to copy 'Template' sheet!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    newRow.Range.Cells(1, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List of Assets").Range("M7").Value
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List of Assets").Range("M7").Copy
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed to copy and paste data from 'List of Assets'!", vbExclamation
    End If
    
    currentSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Once each sheet is added I need that sheet to be without gridlines. not sure how to do this? I am on a Mac

Comment: `worksheets("blahblah").DisplayGridlines = False`

Comment: but where in the worksheet do I put that? And also in my workbook worksheet names change all the time based off of values in the list of assets worksheet

Comment: `newSheet.DisplayGridlines = False`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to know sheets' name if you want to disable it for all sheets.

```
    ' get rid of gridlines on all sheets
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, oWB As Workbook
    Set oWB = ThisWorkbook ' Modify as needed
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sht.DisplayGridlines = False
    Next
```